# Independence between two vectors in this specific case.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $g_1, g_2,\ldots, g_K$ be $K$ i.i.d. complex in $\mathbb{C}^N$ (Gaussian with zero mean and unit variance) vectors. Let $G=[g_1, g_2,\ldots, g_K]^*$, where $[\cdot]^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose, and where $K \le N$. For matrix $G$, we define $G_1=[\bar{g}_1, \bar{g}_2,\ldots, \bar{g}_K]^*$, where $\bar{g}_i=\frac{g_i}{\| g_i\|}$. Suppose that $w_1$ is a unit norm vector that lies in the null space of $g_2,\ldots, g_K$.

My goal is to determine $w_1$. Maybe one way is to calculate the (Moore-Penrose) pseudo-inverse of $G_1$, as $W=G_1^*(G_1G_1^*)^{-1}$ (or simply the inverse if it exists), so $w_1$ is the first column of $W$ after normalization  -- Is it correct ? -- In this case, *can we claim that $w_1$ and $g_1$ are independent* (i.e. independency of random variables)?

Also, what choice of $w_1$ maximizes the product $|g^*_1w_1|$ ?

**P.S**.: my main question is about independency and the additional question is not highly required.  In addition, if a general result is difficult for $K \le N$, I might accept an answer for the specific case where $N=K$.

Comment: Plz don't hesitate to modify the title or the text (or even the tags) if necessary.

Comment: You want to determine $w_1$. Is there any reason to assume that $w_1$ is unique (up to a phase multiplier)? Can we have, say, $K=2$ and the vectors $g_i\in\Bbb{C}^{100}$? IOW have we any control of the dimension of the common null space.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen about the uniqueness of $w_1$, I didn't really get your point. For the dimension of the null space, all what we know is that $K \le N$ and that the difference between $K$ and $N$ is not that large. Aslo, I am intersted in the specific case where $N=K$.

Comment: thank you for your valuable comment. I edited the question. Actually my question is not just for $K=N$, but for the more general case. However, I can accept an answer that explains why it's difficult to answer the general case and provide me the result for $K=N$.